# kubernetes control plane goes down often

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, ubuntu-22.04

I did setup a kubernetes cluster using kubeadm. Somehow kubectl refuses to connect to that cluster in non-periodic occasions with an error message as in the following;

```
The connection to the server 192.168.1.3:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I am guessing that my cluster going down and restarting itself? Can someone provide me some insights.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dciQe.png)

Comment: Could be many things, starting with network problems. Check logs on the cluster to see if it restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed docker first which comes with containerd. containerd uses cgroupfs. While kubeadm uses systemd by default. I have realized that kubelet service crashing over and over by checking its log with journalctl.

Now I have installed cri-o instead problem solved.